# SQL query for finding ID by all exact values

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I have a dilemma that I have not been able to figure out.  I've spent plenty of sessions searching google and stackoverflow and was not able to find anything.  Perhaps I just do not know the terminology I should be searching for.  I'm trying to create a SELECT statement to determine which list was used when only provided the list's values.  Multiple lists may have the same values though...

**1.) Mailing Lists:**

- List A: Adam, Brenda, Carl, Doug, Edward, Frank
- List B: Adam, Brenda, Edward
- List C: Doug, Edward

**2.) mailingLists table structure**

```
ListColumn PersonColumn
A Adam
A Brenda
A Carl
A Doug
A Edward
A Frank
B Adam
B Brenda
B Edward
C Doug
C Edward
```

**3.) User provides me the following info:** Adam, Brenda, Edward.

How do I determine the exact list the user mailed to, if only provided the Person(s) when they are associated with multiple Lists?

I've tried multiple variations of "SELECT List FROM mailingLists... WHERE IN (SELECT...)" statements but I always get all the lists associated with the persons (List A & B above), never the single exact list (List B above) returned?

I am in tech support and not one of the developers, so ALTER'ing any table structures to make it easier is not possible.

If this has been covered before sorry!  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks!

*P.S. the DB is using SQL Anywhere if that will make a difference.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using aggregation and `having`:

```
select list
from mailinglists
group by list
having count(*) = sum(case when person in ('Adam', 'Brenda', 'Edward') then 1 else 0 end);
```

This gets lists that have exactly three names and those names are the names provided.  So this would return list B.

If you want both list A and B (all lists that include the names but maybe with other names), then a similar approach works:

```
select list
from mailinglists
where person in ('Adam', 'Brenda', 'Edward') 
group by list
having count(*) = 3;  -- the "3" here is the number of names provided by the user
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon!  This worked however the CASE THEN ELSE did not work for me for some reason.  I had to end up incrementing each time a person was found and then tallying the total count returned using something like this:  "HAVING COUNT(person) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM lists WHERE person IN ("persons list provided by user"))"

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using following two queries

```
mysql> SELECT  LIST,count(*) FROM mailingLists WHERE Person IN ("Adam","Brenda","Edward") GROUP BY LIST;
+------+----------+
| LIST | count(*) |
+------+----------+
| A    |        3 |
| B    |        3 |
| C    |        1 |
+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> (SELECT  LIST,count(*) FROM mailingLists  GROUP BY LIST) ;
+------+----------+
| LIST | count(*) |
+------+----------+
| A    |        6 |
| B    |        3 |
| C    |        2 |
+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

base on matching count you can get the required list

Answer (score 0):

```
with Search(Person) as (
    select 'Adam' union all
    select 'Brenda' union all
    select 'Edward'
)
select
from MailingLists ml left outer join Search s on s.Person = ml.PersonColumn
group by ml.ListColumn
having count(*) = count(s.Person) -- entire list matches up one to one
having count(s.Person) = (select count(*) from Search) -- all search persons found
```

This is similar to Gordon's approach but possibly a little more generic and can handle any number of names to match/search on. You could replace the `Search` list with a query on another table, for example. Select one of the two `having` clauses depending on the nature of your desired matches. Another thing to note is that duplicate names in the search list would mess up the results.